# Custom info type and hotword rule

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

Trying to use customInfoType combined with the hotwordRule. The configuration looks like this (taken from `nodeJS` implementation):

custom info type:

```
const customConfig = [{
    infoType: {
      name: 'CZECH_ID'
    },
    regex: {
      pattern: /[0-9]{2,6}-?[0-9]{2,10}\/[0-9]{4}/
    },
    likelihood: 'POSSIBLE'
  }];
```

custom rule set:

```
const customRuleSet = [{
    infoTypes: [{ name: 'CZECH_ID' }],
    rules: [
      {
        hotwordRule: {
          hotwordRegex: {
            pattern: /^CZID$/
          }
        },
        proximity: {
          windowBefore: 10,
          windowAfter: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
```

and here the `inspectConfig`:

```
const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/global`,
    inspectConfig: {
      infoTypes: infoTypes,
      customInfoTypes: customConfig,
      ruleSet: customRuleSet,
      minLikelihood: 'POSSIBLE',
      limits: {
        maxFindingsPerRequest: maxFindings,
      },
      includeQuote: true,
    },
    item: item,
  };
```

When running it I get:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: `window_before` and `window_after` cannot both be 0.
```

When I remove the `customeRuleSet` from the run configuration it passes, without identifying the string though. So it has to do something with the `proximity` section, not sure what is wrong though.

Comment: What happens if you add likelihood_adjustement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json looks off, you aren't including proximity inside of the hotword rule.

```
hotword_rule = {
        "hotword_regex": {"pattern": "/^CZID$/"},
        "likelihood_adjustment": {
            "fixed_likelihood": google.cloud.dlp_v2.Likelihood.VERY_LIKELY
        },
        "proximity": {"window_before": 10},
    }

    rule_set = [
        {"info_types": [{"name": "CZECH_ID"}], "rules": [{"hotword_rule": hotword_rule}]}
    ]
```

There is a python example here

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes-likelihood#dlp_inspect_hotword_rule-python

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was in the blind spot. Thank you.